# Parse.com Files Not Updating, lead to broken links from data browser

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

So in my js code, the user is making mosaic images. When they press upload, I create a new object and all is good, my code works perfectly. I then save the id to that object that was just uploaded. If the user presses the upload button again, I want to simply use that same object id and clear out the files that were saved before and use the newest version. All of my saves, updates, and everything appear to be working just fine. When I go to the data browser though, I see the files but when I click, the link is broken. (Which doesn't seem it like it should even be possible). 95% of my code is below, there is some stuff outside of that to generate the mosaic image and to store the id returned. How can I avoid these broken links?

```
var ins_file = new Parse.File("Instructions.png", { base64: img_ins_InBase64 }, "image/png");
    var pretty_file = new Parse.File("Pretty.png", { base64: img_pretty_InBase64 }, "image/png");


    ins_file.save().then(function () {
    }, function (error) {
        console.log("Instruction File couldn't be saved")
        // The file either could not be read, or could not be saved to Parse.
    });

    pretty_file.save().then(function () {
    }, function (error) {
        console.log("Mosaic File couldn't be saved")
        // The file either could not be read, or could not be saved to Parse.
    });

    var mosaicClass = Parse.Object.extend("Mosaics");
    var mosaicObj = new Parse.Object("Mosaics");


    var query = new Parse.Query(mosaicClass);
    query.get(parseId, {
        success: function (objToUpdate) {
            // The object was retrieved successfully. SIMPLY UPDATE
            objToUpdate.set("img_ins", ins_file);
            objToUpdate.set("img_pretty", pretty_file);

            objToUpdate.save().then(function () {
                console.log("Initial Image updated");
                var ins_img_url = objToUpdate.get('img_ins').url();
                var pretty_img_url = objToUpdate.get('img_pretty').url();

                objToUpdate.set("img_ins_url", ins_img_url);
                objToUpdate.set("img_pretty_url", pretty_img_url);

                objToUpdate.save();

                console.log("Mosaic updated, id was: " + objToUpdate.id);

                parseId = objToUpdate.id;


            }, function (error) {
                console.log("File couldn't be updated")
                // The file either could not be read, or could not be saved to Parse.
            });
        },
        error: function (object, error) {
            // The object was not retrieved successfully.
            // parseId was null so make a new thing

            mosaicObj.set("img_ins", ins_file);
            mosaicObj.set("img_pretty", pretty_file);

            mosaicObj.save().then(function () {
                console.log("Initial Images uploaded");
                var ins_img_url = mosaicObj.get('img_ins').url();
                var pretty_img_url = mosaicObj.get('img_pretty').url();

                mosaicObj.set("img_ins_url", ins_img_url);
                mosaicObj.set("img_pretty_url", pretty_img_url);

                mosaicObj.save();

                console.log("Mosaic Saved, id was: " + mosaicObj.id);

                parseId = mosaicObj.id;


            }, function (error) {
                console.log("File couldn't be saved")
                // The file either could not be read, or could not be saved to Parse.
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: It appears you're not waiting for them to save before assigning them.  Async JS will get you every time.

Comment: So put my ObjToUpdate.set(..) inside the file.save().then() function? If that's not the case, can you please just copy the code into your answer and I will give you +25 rep :)

Comment: Yes, you should be saving the file object on the parse object only after the save, inside the then.  You can put both file saves in an array and use Parse.Promise.when([promise1, promise2]).then(... too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you're not waiting for the files to save before trying to assign them to a parse object.  Async JS will get you every time.

You should be saving the file object on the parse object only after the save, inside the then. You can put both file saves in an array and use `Parse.Promise.when([promise1, promise2]).then(...);` too.

Comment: So the code actually does work correctly, I had changed how I got the data from the canvas awhile back and it turns out I forgot to verify that it still was working the old way before moving on to the new way. Thanks for the help though!